# Search files in Modern view SharePoint online libraries by their name

Tags: search, modern-experience, sharepoint-library, metadata-navigation

In classic SharePoint libraries, there was a small search box for filtering or searching files by their metadata including their filename. In the modern view seems there is no such option. even in metadata navigation, the file name is not among the options. Can you please let me know how I can simply search files by their name?

[image: Classic library Search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a search box above the left-hand menu (quick launch):
[image]

It will scope to only search in the document library when you are on a view of the library